# 2D spcae: How to do vector prediction for intersect point of one circular motion & one linear motion object?

Tags: math, vector, 2d, prediction

In a 2D space,

Object A is in uniform circular motion around a fixed point..

Object B is in linear motion, trying to target & hit the object A..

(eg: a bullet (object B) trying to hit a pole on the marry-go-round (object A) in top-down prespective)

Assuming both of their speeds to be constant, How can i calculate the intersection point, i.e. where to target with object B?
So that I know the direction of object B has to take from from its initial position to collide with the object A..

I have looked around for solutions but most are vector predictions about two linearly moving objects..
I really would appericate any tips or advices!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

When an object (in your case A) is moving along a circular path, then it's position over time t can be described as:

```
x1 = r X cos (w . t)
y1 = r X cos (w . t)

where w is uniform angular speed in radians/second
```

On the other hand, linear speed is

```
x2 = velocity X time X cos (theta)
y2 = velocity X time X sin (theta)
```

Now collision/hitting means:

```
x1 = x2
y1 = y2
```

just solve above linear equations for t and theta. Finally direction will be starting point of bullet and point (x, y).